# ajax file upload with async

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, fastcgi

I am trying to upload a text file to a python script.  If I just upload form data and use

```
form_contents = $(this).serialize() + "&async=true";
```

then the form will stay on the web page and display the results.  If I use

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
```

it submits the form and data file but it doesn't stay on the web page.  How do I add  + `&async=true` to get it to stay on the web page.  Or is there a different way to do this?

Stays on web page but doesn't upload file:

> ```
>           $('#upload').submit(function () {
>       form_contents = $(this).serialize() + "&async=true";
>       form_action = $(this).attr('action');
>
>       $.ajax({
>       type: 'post',
>           data: formData,
>       url: form_action,
>       success: function (result) {
>       $('#upload').html(result);
>       } 
>       });
>       return false;
>   });
> ```

Doesn't stay on web page but uploads file:

```
$('#upload').submit(function () {
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    form_action = $(this).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    xhr: function() {
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ 
        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false);
    }
    return myXhr;
    },
    data: formData,
    url: form_action,
    success: function (result) {
        $('#upload').html(result);
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
```

Thanks for your help,

Matt

Comment: Put an `event` parameter in your submit function and call `event.preventDefault();` at the very top of the function, the check your console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also set the contentType and processData parameters to false.

```
$('#upload').submit(function () {
  var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
  form_action = $(this).attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    xhr: function () {
      myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      if (myXhr.upload) {
        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
      }
      return myXhr;
    },
    data: formData,
    url: form_action,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {
      $('#upload').html(result);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

however, if an error occurs, the form will continue to submit because it never reaches `return false;`. to stop that so you can see the error, use event.preventDefault.

```
$('#upload').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
  form_action = $(this).attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    xhr: function () {
      myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      if (myXhr.upload) {
        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
      }
      return myXhr;
    },
    data: formData,
    url: form_action,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {
      $('#upload').html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't you just simply add a hidden input element to the form?
`<input type=hidden name="async" value="true">`
...then this value would automatically be a part of your serialized data in `formData`